# Multiple LINQ to XML query

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to figure out a multiple where clause that is derived from two different elements. Basically, I want to be able to filter based on name attributes of DataType & Service elements. Appreciate any feedback. Thanks Jay

```
var services = from dt in doc.Descendants("DataType")
               where (string)dt.Attribute("name") == "WELL_INDUSTRY" && (string)dt.Elements("Service").Attributes == "Well_Industry"
               from service in dt.Elements("Services").Elements("Service").Elements("Layers").Elements("Layer")
               select new
               {
                   Name = (string)service.Attribute("name"),

               };
```

XML:

```
<DataTypes>
  <DataType name="WELL_INDUSTRY">
    <Spatial>
      <Services>
        <Service name="Well_Industry" group="Well" status="Primary" >
          <Layers>
            <layer name="Bottom Hole Wells" ></layer>
           <layer name="Bottom Hole Wells2" ></layer>
          </Layers>
```

Comment: Well, you've *shown* a where clause using multiple attributes... so what's wrong? (Other than you're trying to compare the result of the `Attributes` property with a string...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like that:

```
var services = from dt in doc.Descendants("DataType")
               where (string)dt.Attribute("name") == "WELL_INDUSTRY"
               from service in dt.Element("Spatial")
                                 .Elements("Services")
                                 .Elements("Service")
               where (string)service.Attribute("name") == "Well_Industry"
               from layer in service.Element("Layers")
                                    .Elements("Layer")
               select new
               {
                   ServiceName = (string)service.Attribute("name"),
                   Layers = layer.Select(x => (string)x).ToList()
               };
```

1. You can add another `where` after `from service ...`.
2. You are still able to use `service` variable within `select` part of the query.

However, querying for `ServiceName` when there is `ServiceName == "myName"` check before seems to be useless. In case you need names of layers, use following `select`:

```
               select new
               {
                   Name = (string)layes.Attribute("name")
               };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var services = from dt in doc.Descendants("DataType")
               where (string)dt.Attribute("name") == "WELL_INDUSTRY"
               from s in dt.Descendants("Service")
               where (string)s.Attribute("name") == "Well_Industry"
               from l in s.Descendants("Layer")
               select new { 
                    Name = (string)l.Attribute("name") 
               };
```

Same can be achieved with XPath:

```
var xpath = "//DataType[@name='WELL_INDUSTRY']//Service[@name='Well_Industry']//layer";
var services = from l in doc.XPathSelectElements(xpath)
               select new {
                    Name = (string)l.Attribute("name")
               };
```